# Why is Dynamic linking taking so much time?

Tags: c++, linux, performance, static-linking, dynamic-linking

So I wrote a very very basic virtual machine that runs on a small subset of c-. I was profiling it to try and see what the bottlenecks were, and the results really confused me. 73% of the time was used in the dl_relocate_object function. Within that function, 85% was spent in _dl_lookup_symbol_x.

I do not know much about the internals of dynamic libraries, but I feel that something is wrong. Based on a little bit of searching, this means that 75% of the time, my program is searching through dynamic libraries for a function. That sounds absurd to me.

When I statically link the binary, there is over a 2x speed improvement and the worst function becomes my VM::run function at 90%. Of that function, 75% is spent in ifstream.

Basically I am wondering if anyone has any idea why this is happening or if it is normal. When I dynamically link, my program runs at about the same speed as an interpreted version of the program that has to lex and parse raw text.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

enum opcodes{halt, loadInt, storeVar, loadVar, readVar, writeInt, writeString,
add, sub, mul, divide, eq, neq, leq, ls, gr, geq, notVal, andVal, orVal};

class VM {
    unsigned long pc;
    vector<int> stack;
    ifstream imem;
    char buf[1024*64];
    int var[256];
  public:
    VM(char* file){
        imem.open(file);
        imem >> noskipws;
        imem.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(buf, 1024*64);
    }
    void run(){
        int x, y;
        char c;
        char instruction;
        while(imem >> instruction){
            switch(instruction){
                case halt:
                    goto exit_loop;
                case writeString:
                    imem >> c;
                    while(c != 0){
                        cout << c;
                        imem >> c;
                    }
                    cout << endl;
                    break;
                case loadInt:
                    imem >> c;
                    x = (c << 24);
                    imem >> c;
                    x |= (c << 16);
                    imem >> c;
                    x |= (c << 8);
                    imem >> c;
                    x |= c;
                    stack.push_back(x);
                    break;
                case storeVar:
                    imem >> c;
                    var[(int)c] = stack.back();
                    stack.pop_back();
                    break;
                case loadVar:
                    imem >> c;
                    stack.push_back(var[(int)c]);
                    break;
                case readVar:
                    imem >> c;
                    cin >> var[(int)c];
                    break;
                case writeInt:
                    x = stack.back();
                    stack.pop_back();
                    cout << x << endl;
                    break;
                case add:
                    y = stack.back();
                    stack.pop_back();
                    x =stack.back();
                    stack.pop_back();
                    stack.push_back(x + y);
                    break;
                case sub:
                    y = stack.back();
                    stack.pop_back();
                    x =stack.back();
                    stack.pop_back();
                    stack.push_back(x - y);
                    break;
                case mul:
                    y = stack.back();
                    stack.pop_back();
                    x =stack.back();
                    stack.pop_back();
                    stack.push_back(x * y);
                    break;
                case divide:
                    y = stack.back();
                    stack.pop_back();
                    x =stack.back();
                    stack.pop_back();
                    stack.push_back(x / y);
                    break;
                case eq:
                    y = stack.back();
                    stack.pop_back();
                    x =stack.back();
                    stack.pop_back();
                    stack.push_back((int)(x == y));
                    break;
                case neq:
                    y = stack.back();
                    stack.pop_back();
                    x =stack.back();
                    stack.pop_back();
                    stack.push_back((int)(x != y));
                    break;
                case leq:
                    y = stack.back();
                    stack.pop_back();
                    x =stack.back();
                    stack.pop_back();
                    stack.push_back((int)(x <= y));
                    break;
                case ls:
                    y = stack.back();
                    stack.pop_back();
                    x =stack.back();
                    stack.pop_back();
                    stack.push_back((int)(x < y));
                    break;
                case gr:
                    y = stack.back();
                    stack.pop_back();
                    x =stack.back();
                    stack.pop_back();
                    stack.push_back((int)(x > y));
                    break;
                case geq:
                    y = stack.back();
                    stack.pop_back();
                    x =stack.back();
                    stack.pop_back();
                    stack.push_back((int)(x >= y));
                    break;
                case notVal:
                    x = stack.back();
                    stack.pop_back();
                    stack.push_back((int)(!x));
                    break;
                case andVal:
                    y = stack.back();
                    stack.pop_back();
                    x =stack.back();
                    stack.pop_back();
                    stack.push_back((int)(x && y));
                    break;
                case orVal:
                    y = stack.back();
                    stack.pop_back();
                    x =stack.back();
                    stack.pop_back();
                    stack.push_back((int)(x || y));
                    break;
                default:
                    cout << "Error: Unknown Instruction" << endl;
                    goto exit_loop;
            }
        }
        exit_loop: ;
    };
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if(argc <= 1){
        cout << "Bad input" << endl;
    }
    VM vm(argv[1]);
    vm.run();
}
```

Side note, I have tried loading the entire file into a char[] during the initialization of VM and then using the char[] instead of the ifstream during run. I have also tried using an int[] for the stack. Neither of those changes made any difference.

Comment: You include percentages here but not the actual benchmarks you've done. If your program has a total execution time of 2 nanoseconds it's really no wonder the dynamic loading, which has to do multiple IO calls, parsing, table lookups etc ends up taking the majority that; Note that this is cost you pay once at the start of the program, and even then it's not actually a long time in human terms.

Comment: Good advice given here: [Is a DLL slower than a static link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149668/is-a-dll-slower-than-a-static-link)

Comment: Oh and congratulations for using a `goto` that didn't set my teeth wiggling.

Comment: @user4581301 the `goto` here is literally just a worse version of `return;`

Comment: @Cubic The `while` loop can be bundled into a function to kill ithe `goto` but the point is it didn't have me retching and screaming "Why, God? Why?"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to some comments above and this link [Is a DLL slower than a static link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149668/is-a-dll-slower-than-a-static-link) I decided to test with a much larger input and got the expected results. Apparently the loop iterations are so fast that even with 1_000 iterations, the dynamic linking still took most of the time. With 1_000_000 iterations, the code preformed as expected. Both the static and dynamic run in very similar times. Also, when looking at 1_000_000 instructions, it runs about 9x faster than the interpreter.

Side note, I originally had instructions after the while loop and that is why I had the goto. I later removed them. I guess it is obsolete now.